# C# 4.0 object oriented time contraints

Tags: c#, object, oop

I have many `if` statements inside a `for` loop and I'm looking for an alternative other than a `switch` statement.  Which is best in term of time constraints?

My code:

```
anotherlist

foreach(x objx in xlist)
{
if(objx.att1=anotherlist.someatt)
        do something

if(objx.att2=anotherlist.someatt)
        do something

if(objx.att3=anotherlist.someatt)
        do something
...
```

This continues for around 15 to 20 `if` statements.

Can anyone recommend an alternative?

Comment: What do you mean with "time constraints" here?

Comment: time contraints meaning here faster in terms of exceution time

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator, using it in the condition might not be what you want. In fact as far as I know the compiler will issue a warning or depending on the variable type, a syntax error. Use `==` for comparison.

Answer (score 4):

I have an alternative, though it will not be better in terms of time, but it could be cleaner.

You could have a dictionary, the keys of the dictionary are all the `anotherlist.someatt` possibilities, and the values are detegates of  'do something' functions.

Then you could simply do `DictionaryName[objx.att1].invoke(params)` instead of all these `if(condition...)`.

Comment: @Tanaji: that comes across very impolite. Are you paying Jonathan by the hour?

Comment: actually a switch statement may be compiled into a dictionary (optimizer). But the OPs code is not suitable for a switch, that leaves this.

Comment: @Tanaji: You have lost my cooperation.